# Select multiple rows from a table and add value inputs column

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to select several rows from a table and add the values ​​in the quantities column. This is my table in the html.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="table-responsive">

            <table class="table table-striped" id="table" style="margin-top: 1%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Artículo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Recogida</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; let i=index">
                        <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.recogida}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="OK" class="ok" value="OK"/>

        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

The data comes from my ts like this:

```
`export class EntryOrderLinesComponent implements OnInit {

  articulos = [
    {
      "articulo": "385/65X22.5 HANKOOK AH51 160K (3003836)",
      "cantidad": "94",
      "recogida": "0",
    },
    {
      "articulo": "385/65X22.5 HANKOOK TH31 164K (3003309)",
      "cantidad": "60",
      "recogida": "0",
    },

  ]

  datosEmpresaTaller: Observable<EmpresaTaller>;


  constructor(private datosService: DatosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosEmpresaTaller = this.datosService.getEmpresaTaller();
  }


 }`
```

I need to be able to select multiple rows from the table and have the quantity column added to me when selecting the rows, for example, 94 + 60 and show me the result.

Thank you

I have tried to do it with the click event on the rows but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: In general there's two options for row selection - click (and highlight) or checkboxes. Seems you're a fan of the former, so how have you tried to add the click event and hook it all up? Provide some code examples of what you've tried for us to adjust rather than provide an entire solution (if nothing else because I don't have time to provide one right now).

Comment: I added "let item of articles; let i=index" and another td with {{ i }} with an event (click)="selected(i)" but it does nothing. I deleted the code and I don't remember exactly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some time to kill; here's the approximate basic version of something I'd throw together for this.

Slap your click event in, and, I guess, something to show it's selected:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; let i=index" 
    (click)="onRowClicked(item)"
    [class.selected]="isRowSelected(item)">
    ...
</tr>
```

```css
.selected { background-color: blackasmyheart; }
```

With your basic list of selected items (assuming you don't extend your `articulos` items with a `selected` flag):

```js
private _selectedItems: any[] = [];

public isRowSelected(item: any): boolean {
    return this._selectedItems.includes(item);
}

public onRowClicked(item: any): void {
    if (this.isRowSelected(item)) this._selectedItems.remove(item);
    else this._selectedItems.push(item)
}
```

And voila, you now have a list available with all of your selected items to do with as you desire.

Edit:

Oh, right, JS/TS, I forgot - grab the index of the item, splice it out of the array.

```js
const idx = this._selectedItems.indexOf(item);
this._selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
```

Comment: It tells me: The property 'remove' does not exist in the type 'any[]'.ts(2339)